# subtracting std_logic_vector from integer

Tags: vector, integer, logic, vhdl, subtraction

I have a problem subtracting a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR from a integer.

This is the code I have right now:

```
entity ROM is
    Port (  hcount: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
            vcount: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
            hpos: in integer;
            vpos: in integer;
            clk25: in STD_LOGIC;
            Pixeldata: out std_logic);
end ROM;

architecture Behavioral of ROM is

signal romtemp : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
shared variable yas : integer range 0 to 9 := 0;
shared variable xas : integer range 0 to 9 := 0;

Type RomType is array (9 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    Constant Rom: RomType := 
     ( "0001111000", "0111111110", "0111111110", "1111111111", "1111111111"
     , "1111111111", "1111111111", "0111111110", "0111111110", "0001111000");

begin
process(clk25)
begin
    if(hpos > hcount - 10) and (hpos <= hcount) and (vpos > vcount - 10) and (vpos <= vcount) then
    xas := hpos - to_integer(unsigned(hcount));
        
    end if;

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The problem is the following line of code:

```
xas := hpos - to_integer(unsigned(hcount));
```

I am trying to put the subtraction in the integer named xas.

The following errors occur on that line:

> Error: Multiple declarations of unsigned included via multiple use clauses; none are made directly visible
>
> Error: Expecting type unsigned for < unsigned(hcount) >.
>
> Error: Formal < arg > has no actual or default value.
>
> Error: Type integer is not an array type and cannot be indexed
>
> Error: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overload matching definition for "-"

Someone that can help me with this error? (I am a beginner in VHDL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included your `use` clauses at the top of the file, but what this error is saying is that from the `use` clauses, it found two different definitions of `unsigned`. Because of this, the tool has ignored both definitions, generating an error and forcing you to deal with the problem.

The most likely explanation is that you have:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
```

`std_logic_arith` is nonstandard, and you should implement your design using the types and functions available in `numeric_std` only. Remove the `std_logic_arith` line.

In general, if something is a number, use a numeric type to represent it. For example, your `hcount` and `vcount` inputs are clearly counters, and could use type `unsigned`. If you use more appropriate types in the first place, you avoid the need for awkward looking type conversions, for example:

```
xas := hpos - to_integer(unsigned(hcount));
```

would become

```
xas := hpos - hcount;
```

---

Additional problems in your code:

- Your process sensitivity list contains only `clk25`, but the process is not actually a synchronous process, and so all the input signals used should be in the list (or you can use the reserved `all` keyword to generate an automatic list, i.e. `process(all)`).
- Unless this is some special case, you are better off getting into the habit of writing synchronous processes. These look like this:

---

```
process(clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    -- Do things
  end if;
end process;
```

---

- `xas` is a shared variable, which implies that you might be assigning it in other processes as well. This will probably not work how you expect it to. You should avoid shared variables altogether until you have a good understanding of exactly how they work, and when it might be appropriate to use them.

Comment: The last item is very important. Try not to use shared variables, unless you know what you are doing. Use variables in the process scope, or use signals in the architecture scope. If that does not work for what you are trying to achieve, then I expect you are coming from a different programming language. VHDL is a hardware design language: a lot is possible in the code, but in the end you still have to think of it as registers and logic. Not everything is possible there, like for instance zero propagation delay.